# How to make Text to look like same with respect to length (width) and height in all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-screen

I have a text screen in the bottom and aligned left to the screen and the button which is also in the bottom aligned right to the screen. I have given the size as a 36 sp , but on Samsung tab 4 7'(tvdpi) it looks fine , but on the device S4 (xxhdpi) the text goes behind the button. Where as I want the text to get flexible and to adjust itself.

The Text view in my xml goes like this :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New tools Available"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/tv_new_tools_available"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
```

What I want :

I want that my text should look good in all devices and should not be overlap with the button and it should look good not screw on large devices and should not look bigger in small device

I am wondering How can I achieve this , please help me as I am a newbie in the android. I did research in regards but found that I should use sp instead of dp, but this also created problem for me . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use text font sizes from dimension folders wrt device sizes.

Comment: It should be comment dude !

Comment: No Dude ! its generic answer !

Comment: There is various Values folder under res like res - > Values-w<device size in dp> - > dimens.xml, where you have to define your text font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
           />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button"
          />


    </LinearLayout>
```